# Why do we need VLAN tagging when there's already MAC address table to refer to

Tags: switch, vlan, mac-address

Why do we need VLAN tagging when there's already MAC address table to refer to?

Switch A VLAN 10 -> Switch B VLAN 10

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because we need to add tags to frames on trunk interfaces so that the other end of the trunk link knows which frames belong to which VLANs.

In your example, with a single VLAN shared across two switches, you do not need to trunk, and would not have VLAN tags if you don't. If you had multiple VLANs on both switches, then you need to tag the frames between the switches, otherwise you end up leaking frames between VLANs, which leads to problems.

Comment: lets take it as theres vlan 20 on both side too such that vlan tagging is needed. You mentioned that adding tag such that other end of the trunk link knows. However, cant it just refer to the existing mac address table entry and from there derive the way?

Comment: What if the destination MAC address is not in the MAC address table of the other switch, or if the destination MAC address is the broadcast or a multicast address. You would be sending unnecessary traffic to the interfaces of a different VLAN. Think if only one of 48 interfaces on the other switch were in the target VLAN, that means you send that traffic to 47 interfaces in other VLANs. A VLAN is a broadcast domain, designed to limit broadcasts, and you are defeating that.